# Problem importing csv files to pandas to avoid "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: excel, pandas, csv, spyder

I'm trying to learn python / pandas.  I'm working through "Foundations for Analytics for Python' but have hit a wall

using

```
input_file = sys.argv[1]
```

gives result

> File "C:\Users\longr\Desktop\pfile\1excel_introspect_workbook.py", line 11, in 
>       input_file = sys.argv[1]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

In previous excercises replacing this call with

```
input_file = 'supplier_data.csv'
```

works... [for a csv file]  I've used the source code from github - same error.  All my files [.py / .xlsx / .csv] are together in C:\Users\longr\Desktop\pfile\ .... but I'm at a loss

Can anyone help please?

```
import sys
from xlrd import open_workbook

input_file = sys.argv[1]

workbook = open_workbook(input_file)
print('Number of worksheets:', workbook.nsheets)
for worksheet in workbook.sheets():
    print("Worksheet name:", worksheet.name, "\tRows:", worksheet.nrows, "t\Columns:", worksheet.ncols)
```

Comment: I'm not sure because I dont know how you run your scrpt, but sys.argv is an array indexed from zero. so probably you should run like this python name-of-script.py name-of-file.xlsx. And if you run it like this then no idea until see you edited code

Comment: Thanks for your comments :).really appreciate your input... I need to.solve this so I can (eventually) concatenate multiple files using a search string for multiple files with similar file names or types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv[1]` is the third input that you enter to run your script after the name of your python file.
let's say your py script is named `example.py` then you will run it like

```
python example.py
```

but if you want to get the csv file as `argv[1]` then you need to run your script like

```
python example.py supplier_data.csv
```

now your 
`argv[0] == example.py` and
`argv[1] == supplier_data.csv` as string type.

Answer (score 0):

After some futher hunting I found this site
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWaerL6-OiU
which solved the problem I had with reading in multiple excel sheets

```
#import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob

#### Combine, concatenate, join multiple excel files in a given folder into one dataframe, Each excel files having multiple sheets 
#### All sheets in a single Excel file are first combined into a dataframe, then all the Excel Books in the folder
#### Are combined to make a single data frame. The combined data frame is the exported into a single Excel sheet.


#path = r'C:\Users\Tchamna\Downloads\UTRC_DATA\495GowanusSpeedData20152016'
path = r'C:\Users\Tchamna\Downloads\UTRC_DATA\test'

filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
print(filenames)

### Dataframe Initialization
concat_all_sheets_all_files = pd.DataFrame()


for file in filenames:

        ### Get all the sheets in a single Excel File using  pd.read_excel command, with sheet_name=None
        ### Note that the result is given as an Ordered Dictionary File
        ### Hell can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs...

        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=None,nrows=None,usecols=None,header = 0,index_col=None)
        #df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=0,nrows=34,usecols=105,header = 9,index_col=None)

        #print(df)

        ### Use pd.concat command to Concatenate pandas objects as a Single Table.
        concat_all_sheets_single_file = pd.concat(df,sort=False)



         ### Use append command to append/stack the previous concatenated data on top of each other 
        ### as the iteration goes on for every files in the folder

        concat_all_sheets_all_files=concat_all_sheets_all_files.append(concat_all_sheets_single_file)
        #print(concat_all_sheets)
```